# Assign Elements of Array associate another Array

Tags: php

Assign matrix elements to associate another matrix
My situation is next they have 4 parameters received from a form

```
1 parameter = name = Deep Jhon
2 parameter = Correlative = 5
3 parameter = Quantity = 10000
4 parameter = Diferent Code = Array
```

but the parameter 4 of getting dinamic entry with jquery these are different unique codes  this is set as an array

Example

```
| 1 parameter | 2 Parameter | 3 Parameter | 4 Parameter |

| Jhon Deep       5             10000         Array (4515-6,4879-0,7847-1)
```

I need to establish in this way

```
| 1 parameter | 2 Parameter | 3 Parameter | 4 Parameter |
| Jhon Deep      5             10000          4515-6
| Jhon Deep      5             10000          4879-0
| Jhon Deep      5             10000          7847-1
```

Solution

```
$arrayNew = array("4515-6","4879-0","7847-1");

$dato1 = "Jhon Deep";
$dato2 = "5";
$dato3 = "10000";
$dato4 = $arrayNew;

$data = array($dato1,$dato2,$dato3,$dato4);

$nuevo = array();
for($i= 0; $i < count($dato4); $i++ ){
    array_push($nuevo, array(
        $data[0],
        $data[1],
        $data[2],
        $data[3][$i]
    ));
}
echo print_r($nuevo);
echo var_dump($nuevo);
```

Comment: i can not even read you question.  please edit and make it redable

Comment: Just foreach  with 4th parameter

Comment: I have four parameters three parameters I get a form but 4 is an array that I get from a dynamic input and are different codes what I want is to create a single array by adding the three parameters to each element of the array that I am getting from the input dynamics if you can see the example the last parameter four is an array what I want is for each array of the fourth element to add the parameters 1, 2 and 3